# swift core data migration to change attribute type

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a iOS app that has a core data database for news. Each of the news entities has a ID attribute, which should be a Integer but until now, it is a String and I want to change it to be a Integer.

Steps I have tried until now:

1. Created a new model version and changed the type of the ID attribute from String to Int 32
2. Created a mapping model, where ID has the value expression **FUNCTION($entityPolicy, "idToInt:" , $source.id)**
3. Defined a subclass of NSEntityMigrationPolicy where I have defined the **idToInt** function mentioned above:

```
import CoreData

class ModelV2MigrationPolicy: NSEntityMigrationPolicy {
    func idToInt(old: String) -> Int32 {
        return Int32(old)!
    }
}
```

4. Linked migration policy to mapping model by setting **Custom Policy** to **myapp.ModelV2MigrationPolicy**

But if I now try to run my app, it crashes with the following error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[myapp.ModelV2MigrationPolicy idToInt]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your selector in `FUNCTION($entityPolicy, "idToInt:" , $source.id)` is wrong.

Based on your method `func idToInt(old: String)` the selector should be `"idToIntWithOld:"`

Comment: Now I get a **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** with no information at **container.loadPersistentStores** in AppDelegate --> any ideas?